# Can't save PNG image into file

Tags: c++, image, qt, save, png

I have some troubles with image saving. I have to crop "1.png" by rect and save it to file, but an empty one is appearing (0 bytes). What am I doing wrong?

```
void RedactorForm::cropButtonSlot(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    QImage pixmap("1.png");
    QRect rect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    pixmap=pixmap.copy(rect);

    QString fileName("D:/yourFile.png");
    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    QDataStream out(&file);
    pixmap.save(fileName,0,100);
    out <<pixmap;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using the shorter version `image.save(path)`? Also, you are not checking the result of `open()` - that's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QImage's save method does not take a file name as a parameter, it taske a QFile. Try this;

```
    pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
```

Comment: This does not work. PNG file is not creating at all.

Comment: I'm sure that the save works. Your copy probably doesn't. look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681554/dividing-qimage-to-smaller-pieces

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `QDataStream` for this task. Use directly `save` method of `QImage`. Your code should be like this:

```
QImage pixmap("1.png");

...................

QString fileName("D:/yourFile.png");
QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate)) {
    pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
}
else {
    qDebug() << "Can't open file: " << fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close the file which you opened before. Also you don't need to open the file at all. You can do that:

```
QRect rect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
QImage pixmap(x2-x1,y2-y1,QImage::Format_ARGB32);
pixmap.copy(rect);

QFile file("D:/yourFile.png");
pixmap.save(file.fileName(),"PNG");
```